# can't use /fill in a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just asking if it is possible to use the /fill command in a command block or if i have just written it wrong.....

pls answer,
thanks

[image: Shows /Fill command not working?]

Comment: did you intend to use relative number but forgot to add ~ ?

Comment: What version are you using and are you using any mods? It's also possible the command block is not being activated properly and is showing an old error message. Can you copy/paste the exact command here, directly copy/pasting from the command block? There could be hidden characters and you may need to delete the command block's contents and re-type the command manually.

Comment: Try '/fill ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ stone' in the command block and see if it works.

Comment: The command is apparently written correctly, so the only problem could be caused by the command block never being powered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use the fill command in command blocks, yes, you *might* have written it wrong.

---

In my command blocks I type commands without the preceding `/`, so I'd type:

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName>
```

Also, I'm guessing you were meant to use relative coordinates, coordinates which, in your case, will fill an area near the command block.

Try this command instead:

[image: fill ~16 ~ ~7 ~1 ~ ~19 air]

This will fill an area starting 1 block West and 19 blocks South of the command block, to 16 blocks West, 7 blocks South, with air.

Comment: uhm, idk really because if I write the same command in my chat it works. I also don't use the ~ because its the actual co-ordinates that i want to change, not a distance away from the command block. If you want to know the project, it supposed to be a disappearing floor when you decide a game mode (Single or Multiplayer) where in Single player the floor appears and in Multiplayer its gone so the players would have to parkour to get to one another.

Comment: @BenDerPanda So wait, your world is literally 1 block high above the void?

Comment: @theonlygusti Or the likely case, the floor is one block thick. You do know you can have air blocks under non-air blocks, right?

Comment: @sharpturn Yes, I know that, and actually that is exactly what I stated in my comment. You do know what the void is, right?

Comment: The void is a legitimate area under bedrock level (y < 0) where you cannot place blocks. Air (id 0) is a non block, which you can place blocks in.

Comment: @sharpturn OP is trying to fill at an area where y=0, hence just above bedrock.

Comment: @theonlygusti Oh yea suppose so. Sorry for the misunderstanding, my fault. Really should gab paid more attention to the OP. In that case, I agree with you. Building directly above bedrock is always a bad idea